# Regular expression to allow trailing and leading spaces

Tags: regex, space, email-validation

I now validate email addresses like so:

```
[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+
```

Which means that if users accidentally have a trailing or leading space in that address (e.g. when copy/pasting), the expression validates to false.

So I want to allow trailing and leading spaces on the above expression. How can I do so?

Comment: Why not try trimming off the white space BEFORE validating the input? I'm assuming you'll want to store it without the leading and trailing white space anyway.

Comment: Nice to allow spaces at the client side, then trim server side - makes for a slightly better user experience!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `\s*` at the end and start of your regex. `\s*` means white spaces having zero or more occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following Regex:

```
\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+\s*
```